# Load fxml as background process - Javafx

Tags: javafx, task, fxml, fxmlloader

My initial fxml(say `home.fxml`) has a lot of functionalities, hence it takes a lot of time to load completely. So to avoid the time gap between program start and fxml loading  I introduced one more fxml(say `loader.fxml`) with a gif image which should appear while the main fxml is loading. 
The problem is the gif image in my loader.fxml is not moving as in the program is hanging until the home.fxml is loaded completely.
To avoid this I moved the home.fxml loading into a thread as shown in below code.

```
public class UATReportGeneration extends Application {

    private static Stage mainStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Parent loaderRoot = null;
        try {
            loaderRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/uatreportgeneration/fxml/Loader.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UATReportGeneration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Scene loadScene = new Scene(loaderRoot);
        stage.setScene(loadScene);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/uatreportgeneration/Images/logo.png")));

        stage.show();


        mainStage = new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        mainStage.setTitle("Upgrade Analysis");
        mainStage.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/uatreportgeneration/Images/logo.png")));
        setStage(mainStage);

        new Thread(() -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                try {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                    Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/uatreportgeneration/fxml/Home.fxml"));

                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                    mainStage.setScene(scene);
                    mainStage.show();
                    stage.hide();
                    System.out.println("Stage showing");
                    // Get current screen of the stage
                    ObservableList<Screen> screens = Screen.getScreensForRectangle(new Rectangle2D(mainStage.getX(), mainStage.getY(), mainStage.getWidth(), mainStage.getHeight()));
                    // Change stage properties
                    Rectangle2D bounds = screens.get(0).getVisualBounds();
                    mainStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
                    mainStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
                    mainStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
                    mainStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
                    System.out.println("thread complete");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(UATReportGeneration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            });
        }).start();

    }

    public static Stage getStage() {
        return mainStage;
    }

    public static void setStage(Stage stage) {
        mainStage = stage;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

}
```

But after this code also my program is hanging(The gif image is not moving). If I load the fxml outside the `Platform.runLater()`, I get the exception `Not on FX Thread`.

I also tired using `Task()` but from that the gif image is moving but the fxml is not loading in the background, if I try to load the fxml outside `Platform.runLater()`.

Can anyone please help me and tell me how can I correct the code so that my fxml loads in the background without disturbing the foreground process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Task`. You need to arrange to create the scene and update the stage on the FX Application Thread. The cleanest way is to use a `Task<Parent>`:

```
Task<Parent> loadTask = new Task<Parent>() {
    @Override
    public Parent call() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/uatreportgeneration/fxml/Home.fxml"));
        return root ;
    }
};

loadTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    Scene scene = new Scene(loadTask.getValue());

    mainStage.setScene(scene);
    mainStage.show();
    stage.hide();
    System.out.println("Stage showing");
    // Get current screen of the stage
    ObservableList<Screen> screens = Screen.getScreensForRectangle(new Rectangle2D(mainStage.getX(), mainStage.getY(), mainStage.getWidth(), mainStage.getHeight()));
    // Change stage properties
    Rectangle2D bounds = screens.get(0).getVisualBounds();
    mainStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
    mainStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
    mainStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
    mainStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
    System.out.println("thread complete");
});

loadTask.setOnFailed(e -> loadTask.getException().printStackTrace());

Thread thread = new Thread(loadTask);
thread.start();
```

---

Here is a SSCCE using this technique:

main.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>

<VBox spacing="10" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainController">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="24" left="24" right="24" bottom="24"/>
    </padding>
    <TextField />
    <Button fx:id="button" text="Show Window" onAction="#showWindow"/>
</VBox>
```

MainController (uses the `Task` approach shown above):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Button button ;
    @FXML
    private void showWindow() {
        Task<Parent> loadTask = new Task<Parent>() {
            @Override
            public Parent call() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                // simulate long-loading process:
                Thread.sleep(5000);

                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));
                Parent root = loader.load();
                return root ;
            }
        };

        loadTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            Scene scene = new Scene(loadTask.getValue());
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initOwner(button.getScene().getWindow());
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        });

        loadTask.setOnFailed(e -> loadTask.getException().printStackTrace());

        Thread thread = new Thread(loadTask);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

test.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TestController">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="24" left="24" right="24" bottom="24"/>
    </padding>
    <center>
        <Label fx:id="label" text="This is a new window"/>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <Button text="OK" onAction="#closeWindow" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <BorderPane.margin>
                <Insets top="5" bottom="5" left="5" right="5"/>
            </BorderPane.margin>
        </Button>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

TestController:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class TestController {
    @FXML
    private Label label ;
    @FXML
    private void closeWindow() {
        label.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
}
```

Main application:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"))));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Notice that after pressing the button, you can still type in the text field during the five seconds it takes to "load" the FXML, so the UI is remaining responsive.

Comment: I already tried `Task<Parent>`. It gave me exception `IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread`..  Can you please tell me how can I perform it on FX application thread? Using `Platform.runLater` is hanging the first fxml. :(

Comment: Make sure you don't create the Scene or Stage in the background thread. They have to be created on the FX Application Thread, as in the sample code here.

Comment: I tried the code you mentioned above. Still its giving me the same exception.

Comment: Then you are either creating a `Scene` or `Stage` in your FXML, or you are doing something in the controller that is not allowed on the FX Application Thread. Using a `Task` as above is the right general approach; you just have some details wrong. Edit your question to show your attempt at that approach and include the full stack trace you get.

Comment: Updated with complete working example (no IllegalStateExceptions...)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't update the full code as it is huge. I figured out the problem though. I was adding a tooltip in my fxml. After removing that tooltip, It worked. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: If you're still getting the exception, here's a bug saying that there are [a few components](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8093856) *besides `Scene` or `Stage`* that *can't* be created outside of the FX Application thread. `Tooltip` and `ContextMenu` should work as of 8u40, but [`WebView`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087718) has yet to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

your approach using `Task` was already correct. you were just missing a bit more: you were just missing another `Platform#invokeLater()` to update the UI:

```
    new Thread(new Task() {

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            // Simulating long loading
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("home.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            // Updating the UI requires another Platform.runLater()
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainStage.setScene(scene);
                    mainStage.show();
                    stage.hide();
                    System.out.println("Stage showing");
                    // Get current screen of the stage
                    ObservableList<Screen> screens = Screen.getScreensForRectangle(new Rectangle2D(mainStage.getX(), mainStage.getY(), mainStage.getWidth(), mainStage.getHeight()));
                    // Change stage properties
                    Rectangle2D bounds = screens.get(0).getVisualBounds();
                    mainStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
                    mainStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
                    mainStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
                    mainStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
                    System.out.println("thread complete");
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: I tried your code. Its not even going inside the controller of `home.fxml`. The gif is moving as expected but the home.fxml is not loading.

Comment: it was not supposed to be added blindly. though this was my working example: http://pastebin.com/RThnUe7i

Comment: You're squashing all exceptions. Add a `setOnFailed` handler to the task and see if it's throwing anything. I think you get an `IllegalStateException` by creating the `Scene` on the background thread.

Comment: @KnusperPudding I didnt add it blindly... I did all the changes you suggested. Still its giving the same result.

Comment: @HARSHITASETHI have you tried the example? your main issue is using `Thread` with `Runnable`. By the way James_D's answer is a way better.

Comment: @James_D thanks for the advice. I'm still learning but trying to help as good as I can.  - happy for any advice what I can do better.

Comment: @KnusperPudding Yes I tried the example also. Still its not going inside the controller of home.fxml.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @James_D answer. As mentioned by him, Stages and Scene should not be added in background thread, they should be added only in FX main thread.

I have added `tooltips` in my `home.fxml`, which is nothing but a `PopupWindow`. Therefore to the background thread, it appeared as a new stage. Hence it threw `IllegalStateException`. After removing the `tooltips` from the fxml, the fxml was able to load as a background process as there were no stages created in that thread.