# scene swithching in borderpane center form another class in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am creating the window application with the base as the border pane. I defined this border pane in the class. in the center of the border pane, I have placed the anchor pane. this anchor pane is defined in another class controller. in anchor pane, when I clicked the button I want to change the center of the border pane as another scene. how can I make it possible?

[dashboard.fxml it contains the border pane in center odf the border pane i have loaded the homepage.fxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoBI4.png)
[when I press the item button on the dashboard I want to change the center alone like this i.e itempage.fxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VocfN.png)

dashboardcontroller.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTreeView;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class dashboardcontroller implements Initializable  {

@FXML
private JFXButton logout;

@FXML
public  BorderPane basepan;

@FXML
private JFXTreeView<String> menu;

@FXML
private Label time;

@FXML
private Label date;

static AnchorPane fxmlLoader;

ImageView homeicon = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/if_home_126572.png"), 20,20 , true,true));
ImageView itemicon = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/if_Menu_List_Text_Line_Item_Bullet_Paragraph_1654364.png"), 20,20 , true,true));
ImageView locationicon = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/locationpin.png"), 20,20 , true,true));
ImageView salesandpurchaseicon = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/if_analytics_1954530.png"), 20,20 , true,true));
ImageView reporticon = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/if_icon-45-note-list_315263.png"), 20,20 , true,true));
ImageView usersicon = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/if_users_2561497.png"), 20,25 , true,true));
ImageView addnewitem = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/addnew.png"),20,20,true,true));
    public void clock()
{
    Thread clock = new Thread()
{
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy");
                    SimpleDateFormat stf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
                    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();


                Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                time.setText(stf.format(calendar.getTime()));
                                date.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

                            }

                        });

                sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
};
clock.start();
}

public void getmenu(MouseEvent event)
{
    TreeItem<String> item = menu.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if(item.getValue().equals("Items Master"))
    {
        Thread itemthread = new Thread() {
            public void run()
            {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(dashboardcontroller.class.getResource("itempage.fxml"));

                                }catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                fxmlLoader.setMaxHeight(10000);
                                fxmlLoader.setMaxWidth(10000);
                                basepan.setCenter(fxmlLoader);
                            }

                        });
            }
        };
        itemthread.start();
    }else if(item.getValue().equals("Home"))
    {
        Thread homethread = new Thread()
                {
            public void run()
            {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(dashboardcontroller.class.getResource("homepage.fxml"));
                                }catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                fxmlLoader.setMaxHeight(10000);
                                fxmlLoader.setMaxWidth(10000);
                                basepan.setCenter(fxmlLoader);

                            }

                        });
            }
            };
            homethread.start();
    }
}

@FXML
public void itempress()
{
    try {
        fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(dashboardcontroller.class.getResource("itempage.fxml"));

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    fxmlLoader.setMaxHeight(10000);
    fxmlLoader.setMaxWidth(10000);
    basepan.setCenter(fxmlLoader);
}



@FXML
public void logout(ActionEvent event)
{
    final Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
    final Stage stage =(Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
    main.getPrimaryStage().show();


}

@FXML
public void homepress(ActionEvent event)
{
try {

        fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("homepage.fxml"));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    fxmlLoader.setMaxHeight(10000);
    fxmlLoader.setMaxWidth(10000);
    basepan.setCenter(fxmlLoader);
    //System.out.println("home pressed");
}
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    final Tooltip tooltiplogout = new Tooltip();
    tooltiplogout.setText("Logout");
    tooltiplogout.setFont(Font.font("SanSerif",13));
    Tooltip.install(logout, tooltiplogout);
    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Root");
    TreeItem<String> home = new TreeItem<>("Home", homeicon);
    TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<>("Items Master", itemicon);
    TreeItem<String> addnew = new TreeItem<>("Add New" , addnewitem);
    TreeItem<String> location = new TreeItem<>("Location Master", locationicon);
    TreeItem<String> salesandpurchase = new TreeItem<>("Sales and Purchase Master", salesandpurchaseicon);
    TreeItem<String> report = new TreeItem<>("Report Master", reporticon);
    TreeItem<String> users = new TreeItem<>("Users Master", usersicon);
    root.getChildren().add(home);
    root.getChildren().add(item);
    root.getChildren().add(location);
    root.getChildren().add(salesandpurchase);
    root.getChildren().add(report);
    root.getChildren().add(users);
    item.getChildren().add(addnew);
    menu.setRoot(root);
    menu.setShowRoot(false);
    menu.getStyleClass().add("myTree");



    clock();


    try {

        fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("homepage.fxml"));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("dashboard error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    fxmlLoader.setMaxHeight(10000);
    fxmlLoader.setMaxWidth(10000);
    basepan.setCenter(fxmlLoader);


}
public void itemscreenchange()
{
    Thread itemthread = new Thread()
            {
        public void run()
        {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(dashboardcontroller.class.getResource("itempage.fxml"));

                            }catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            fxmlLoader.setMaxHeight(10000);
                            fxmlLoader.setMaxWidth(10000);
                            basepan.setCenter(fxmlLoader);

                        }

                    });
            }
            };
            itemthread.start();
    }
}
```

homepagecontroller.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class homepagecontroller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private AnchorPane pane;

@FXML
private static HBox hbox1;

@FXML
private StackPane stcpane1;

@FXML
private StackPane stkpane2;

@FXML
private HBox hbox2;

@FXML
private JFXButton item;

@FXML
private JFXButton sales_and_purchase;

@FXML
private JFXButton location_master;

@FXML
private JFXButton report_master;

@FXML
private JFXButton users_manager;

@FXML
public TilePane tilpane;

@FXML
public LineChart<String,Double> graph;

@FXML
private CategoryAxis x;

@FXML
private NumberAxis y;

AnchorPane fxmlLoader;





@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    pane.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
    {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue,Number newValue) {

        }

    });
    XYChart.Series<String,Double> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series<String, Double> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gdlashmi?useSSL=false","root","");
        PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT MonthName(`soldoutdate`.`sold date`) AS Date ,SUM(gross_weight) as `Total Weight` FROM soldoutdate JOIN stocklist WHERE soldoutdate.id = stocklist.id and Year(`sold date`) = Year(CURRENT_DATE) AND (stocklist.Purity = \"Regular\" OR stocklist.Purity = \"KDM\") GROUP BY Month(`soldoutdate`.`sold date`)");
        PreparedStatement pst1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT MonthName(`soldoutdate`.`sold date`) AS Date ,SUM(`stocklist`.`gross_weight`) as `Total Weight` FROM soldoutdate JOIN stocklist WHERE soldoutdate.id = stocklist.id and Year(`sold date`) = Year(CURRENT_DATE) AND (stocklist.Purity = \"92M-Silver\" OR stocklist.Purity = \"Silver\") GROUP BY Month(`soldoutdate`.`sold date`)");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        ResultSet rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {

            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(rs.getString(1),Double.valueOf(rs.getDouble(2))));
            series.setName("Gold");

        }
        while(rs1.next())
        {
            //series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(rs1.getString(1),Integer.valueOf(rs1.getInt(2))));
            series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(rs1.getString(1),Double.valueOf(rs1.getDouble(2))));
            series2.setName("Silver");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    graph.getData().add(series);
    graph.getData().add(series2);

}

public void repostiongraph()
{
    graph.setLayoutY(tilpane.getPrefHeight()+10);
}

public void itempress(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{
    //this is the place i want to load the itempage.fxml in the border pane of dashboardcontroller.java 
}


}
```

itempagecontroller.java

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton; 
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTreeTableColumn;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTreeTableView;
import com.jfoenix.controls.RecursiveTreeItem;
import com.jfoenix.controls.datamodels.treetable.RecursiveTreeObject;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;


import application.itempagecontroller.item;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class itempagecontroller implements Initializable{

@FXML
private AnchorPane itempane;

@FXML
private JFXTreeTableView<item> itemlist;

@FXML
private JFXTextField searchtext;

@FXML
private JFXButton searchbtn;

@FXML
private HBox hbox;

@FXML
private JFXComboBox<String> columncombo;

class item extends RecursiveTreeObject<item>{
    StringProperty itemname;
    StringProperty id;
    StringProperty purity;
    StringProperty location;
    StringProperty weight;
    StringProperty createdon;
    StringProperty itemstatus;

    public item(String itemname,String id,String purity,String location,String weight,String createdon,String itemstatus)
    {
        this.itemname = new SimpleStringProperty(itemname);
        this.id = new SimpleStringProperty(id);
        this.purity = new SimpleStringProperty(purity);
        this.location = new SimpleStringProperty(location);
        this.weight = new SimpleStringProperty(weight);
        this.createdon = new SimpleStringProperty(createdon);
        this.itemstatus = new SimpleStringProperty(itemstatus);
    }
}

@FXML
void searchkeypress(KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER))
    {
    itemlist.setPredicate(new Predicate<TreeItem<item>>()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean test(TreeItem<item> cont) {
            String selected = columncombo.getValue().toString();
            Boolean flag = null;
            if(selected == "All")
            {
            flag = cont.getValue().id.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().itemname.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().purity.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().location.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().weight.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().createdon.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().itemstatus.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
            }else if(selected == "ID")
            {
                flag = cont.getValue().id.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
            }else if(selected == "Item Name")
            {
                flag = cont.getValue().itemname.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
            }else if(selected == "Purity")
            {
                flag = cont.getValue().purity.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
            }else if(selected == "Location")
            {
                flag = cont.getValue().location.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
            }else if(selected == "Gross weight")
            {
                flag = cont.getValue().weight.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
            }else if(selected == "Created On")
            {
                flag = cont.getValue().createdon.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
            }else if(selected == "Item Status")
            {
                flag = cont.getValue().itemstatus.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
            }
            return flag;
        }

    });
    }else if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE))
    {
        if(searchtext.getText().toString().length() == 1)
        {
            itemlist.setPredicate(new Predicate<TreeItem<item>>()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean test(TreeItem<item> cont) {
                    String selected = columncombo.getValue().toString();
                    Boolean flag = null;
                    if(selected == "All")
                    {
                    flag = cont.getValue().id.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().itemname.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().purity.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().location.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().weight.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().createdon.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().itemstatus.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "ID")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().id.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Item Name")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().itemname.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Purity")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().purity.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Location")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().location.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Gross weight")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().weight.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Created On")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().createdon.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Item Status")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().itemstatus.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }
                    return flag;
                }

            });             
        }
    }
}
@FXML
public void searchpress(ActionEvent event)
{
    itemlist.setPredicate(new Predicate<TreeItem<item>>()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean test(TreeItem<item> cont) {
                    String selected = columncombo.getValue().toString();
                    Boolean flag = null;
                    if(selected == "All")
                    {
                    flag = cont.getValue().id.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().itemname.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().purity.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().location.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().weight.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().createdon.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText()) || cont.getValue().itemstatus.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "ID")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().id.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Item Name")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().itemname.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Purity")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().purity.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Location")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().location.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Gross weight")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().weight.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Created On")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().createdon.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }else if(selected == "Item Status")
                    {
                        flag = cont.getValue().itemstatus.getValue().contains(searchtext.getText());
                    }
                    return flag;
                }

            });
}
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    ObservableList<String> columnlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList("All","ID","Item Name","Purity","Location","Gross weight","Created On","Item Status");
    columncombo.setValue("All");
    columncombo.setItems(columnlist);
    JFXTreeTableColumn<item,String> itemcol = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Item Name");
    itemcol.setResizable(false);
    itemcol.setSortable(false);
    itemcol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String> param) {

                return param.getValue().getValue().itemname;
            }
            });

    JFXTreeTableColumn<item,String> idcol = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("ID");
    idcol.setResizable(false);
    idcol.setSortable(false);
    idcol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String> param) {

            return param.getValue().getValue().id;
        }
        });

    JFXTreeTableColumn<item,String> puritycol = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Purity");
    puritycol.setResizable(false);
    puritycol.setSortable(false);
    puritycol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String> param) {

            return param.getValue().getValue().purity;
        }
        });

    JFXTreeTableColumn<item,String> loccol = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Location");
    loccol.setResizable(false);
    loccol.setSortable(false);
    loccol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String> param) {

            return param.getValue().getValue().location;
        }
        });

    JFXTreeTableColumn<item,String> weightcol = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Gross Weight");
    weightcol.setResizable(false);
    weightcol.setSortable(false);
    weightcol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String> param) {

            return param.getValue().getValue().weight;
        }
        });

    JFXTreeTableColumn<item,String> createdoncol = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Created On");
    createdoncol.setResizable(false);
    createdoncol.setSortable(false);
    createdoncol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String> param) {

            return param.getValue().getValue().createdon;
        }
        });

    JFXTreeTableColumn<item,String> itemstatuscol = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Item Status");
    itemstatuscol.setResizable(false);
    itemstatuscol.setSortable(false);
    itemstatuscol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<item, String> param) {

            return param.getValue().getValue().itemstatus;
        }
        });
    itempane.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue,Number newValue) {
                idcol.setPrefWidth(((double) newValue / 7) - 15);
                itemcol.setPrefWidth((double) newValue / 7);
                puritycol.setPrefWidth((double) newValue / 7);
                loccol.setPrefWidth((double) newValue / 7);
                weightcol.setPrefWidth((double) newValue / 7);
                createdoncol.setPrefWidth((double) newValue / 7);
                itemstatuscol.setPrefWidth((double)newValue / 7);
                hbox.setPrefWidth((double) newValue);
            }   
            });
    ObservableList<item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gdlashmi?useSSL=false","root","");
        PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT id,product_name,Purity,location,gross_weight,Date(`date&time`),if(flag = 1, \"In Stock\", \"Sold Out\") `Item Status` from stocklist");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            items.add(new item(rs.getString(2),String.valueOf(rs.getInt(1)),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),String.valueOf(rs.getDouble(5))+" Gram",String.valueOf(rs.getDate(6)),rs.getString(7)));

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final TreeItem<item> root = new RecursiveTreeItem<item>(items, RecursiveTreeObject::getChildren);
    itemlist.getColumns().setAll(idcol,itemcol,puritycol,loccol,weightcol,createdoncol,itemstatuscol);
    itemlist.setRoot(root);
    itemlist.setShowRoot(false);

}

}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Give us some code to work with. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Define a method in the class that has the reference to the border pane, and call it on the instance of that class. You need to post a [MCVE] if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: `Threads` to load different `Views`?

Comment: I tried it too. but I do get the thread null pointer Exception @Sedrick

Comment: I am thinking more along the lines of you probably don't need to use `Threads` to load different `Views`.

Comment: here the only problem I am facing is I cant able to get the border pane which is defined in dashboardcontroller.java to the homepagecontroller.java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873673/load-fxml-as-background-process-javafx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create the border pane as an fxml file ad load in whenever you need it

Comment: I already created it as the fxml file only. but I want to load the center part alone when I clicked the button in another fxml which is already in the center border pane

Comment: try with border.setCenter(node); border is the border pane and node is the node you want to add

Comment: Here is the problem that I am facing how can I get the border i.e border pane which is defined in another class

Comment: another class another fxml you can add a static node that load the fxml boarder pane in initialisation like  
`@FXML BorderPane borderPane; 
Public Static BorderPane staticBorderPane; 
@Override
    public void initialize(java.net.URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
{
staticBorderPane=borderPane;
} `
then you gonna access it by static reference

Comment: can you please elaborate it? I cant able to get it

Comment: can you give more information abt the fxml file so i can explain better

Comment: I have added the fxml views as a link above @Yuuuucef

Comment: okey : so what i would do is add a anchor pane inside the borderpane center and give it an ID as we already said then when controller initialize i will put it in static field if i would access it from another controller after is this what you want to do ?!

Answer (score 0):

Create a public class that will accept the data that you need to pass publicly

**ChangeScenes.java**

```
//changes the display in borderpane center

public static void moveToCenter(URL ui, BorderPane borderpane){
try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(ui);
        borderpane.setCenter(root);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ChangeScenes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

then you can call it anywhere you want

**MainController.java**

```
@FXML private BorderPane borderPane;

@FXML
private void handlePersonalInfo(ActionEvent event) {
        ChangeScenes.moveToCenter(getClass().getResource("/AnotherScene.fxml"), borderPane);
    }
```